# How to Convert GDI+'s Image* into Bitmap*

Tags: c++, image, gdi+, bitmap

I am writting code in c++, gdi+.

I make use of Image's GetThumbnail() method to get thumbnail.
However, I need to convert it into HBITMAP.
I  know the following code can get GetHBITMAP:

```
Bitmap* img;
HBITMAP temp;
Color color;
img->GetHBITMAP(color, &temp); // if img is Bitmap*  this works well。
```

But how can I convert Image* into Bitmap* fast?
Many thanks!

Actually, now I have to use the following method:

```
int width = sourceImg->GetWidth(); // sourceImg is Image*
int height = sourceImg->GetHeight();
Bitmap* result = new Bitmap(width, height,PixelFormat32bppRGB);
Graphics gr(result);
//gr.SetInterpolationMode(InterpolationModeHighQuality);
gr.DrawImage(sourceImg, 0, 0, width, height);
```

I really don't know why they do not provide Image* - > Bitmap* method. but let GetThumbnail() API return a Image object....

Comment: The way you do this is fine. The reason why it cannot be converted "fast" in general is because `Image` is not necessarily a bitmap at all - it can be a vector image (though the only vector format I'm aware of that is supported by GDI+ is WMF/EMF). I would imagine that in this case, `GetThumbnail` would produce a vector image as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
Image* img = ???;
Bitmap* bitmap = new Bitmap(img);
```

Edit:
I was looking at the.NET reference of GDI+, but here is how .NET implements that constructor.

```
using (Graphics graphics = null)
{
    graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent);
    graphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
}
```

All  those function are avaliable in the C++ version of GDI+

Comment: I don't see any constructors for `Bitmap` that accept an `Image*`.

Comment: me too~~ , Maybe in .NET it works, but c++ do not provide this constructor

Answer (score 3):

First you may try `dynamic_cast` as in many cases (if not most - at least in my use cases) `Image` is being implemented by `Bitmap` . So

```
Image* img = getThumbnail( /* ... */ );
Bitmap* bitmap = dynamic_cast<Bitmap*>(img);
if(!bitmap)
    // getThumbnail returned an Image which is not a Bitmap. Convert.
else
    // getThumbnail returned a Bitmap so just deal with it.
```

However if somehow it is not (`bitmap` will be `nullptr`) then you could try a more general solution.

For example save the `Image` to a *COM* `IStream` using `Save` method and then use `Bitmap::FromStream` to create `Bitmap` from that stream.

A simple *COM* `IStream` could be created using the [`CreateStreamOnHGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378980.aspx) *WinAPI* function. However this is not efficient, especially for larger streams, but to test the idea it will do.

There are also other similar solutions which can be deduced from reading [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534462.aspx) and [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534420.aspx) documentation.

Sadly I haven't tried it on my own (with `Image` which is not a `Bitmap`) so I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Actually, the code in the question is a perfectly good way of getting a Bitmap out of a generic Image.

Comment: My answer gives potentially optimal solution since cost of dynamic_cast is small (compared to drawing/copying the image) and in most cases I think it will succeed.

If not then either my version or the code in question (added after my answer) is a way to do. The code from question seems simpler and safer thou. However I am not sure how transparency will be handled by it.

Also if possible it could be useful to refactor getThumbnail to return Bitmap* as it does not seem likely that it produces for example a vector graphic.

Comment: I agree that for a Bitmap image, GetThumbnail() Method should return a Image* which points to Bitmap object in fact. 
But After tring it , I found it points to Image object...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell you have to just create a bitmap and paint the image into it:

```
Bitmap* GdiplusImageToBitmap(Image* img, Color bkgd = Color::Transparent)
{
    Bitmap* bmp = nullptr;
    try {
        int wd = img->GetWidth();
        int hgt = img->GetHeight();
        auto format = img->GetPixelFormat();
        Bitmap* bmp = new Bitmap(wd, hgt, format);
        auto g = std::unique_ptr<Graphics>(Graphics::FromImage(bmp));
        g->Clear(bkgd);
        g->DrawImage(img, 0, 0, wd, hgt);
    } catch(...) {
        // this might happen if img->GetPixelFormat() is something exotic
        // ... not sure
    }
    return bmp;
}
```